# How to fix "Missing required dependencies ['numpy']" error?

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

Hello how can i get past this error, I'v tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas and Quandl but it still comes up with the same error?

```
RESTART: C:/Users/Reece92/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Machine learning sentdex IDLE.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):   

File "C:/Users/Reece92/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Machine learning sentdex IDLE.py", line 1, in <module>     
    import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\Reece92\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) 
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: Have you installed `numpy`? (`pip install numpy`)

Comment: This error message is very clear.

Comment: I have also received this too  - and also had previously installed numpy. `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/wbaelen/.virtualenvs/data-proc/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: I have the same problem. This paste won't format correctly since it's a comment, but here is proof that numpy is installed, but I get the same error.
# pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.13.3)
# python3 homepage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mgc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Answer (score 1):

In the python world, you have something called packages. You can use it to extend python with libraries and stuff. By default none of these "extra" packages are a installed, you have to use a command called pip to install all the requirements your application need.

In your case :

```
pip install numpy
```